# How to await the response until the product image is uploaded to GCP, bacause now before I get the response from GCP, code is throwing 404 error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, google-cloud-platform

I'm building a nodejs project to upload a image to GCP and storing the returned string in mongoDB, but before I get reposne from GCP, i get 404 error and then it says
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

```
module.exports.addProductImage = async (request, response, next) => {
    try {
        const { color } = request.body;
        const { id } = request.params;

        if (!request.files?.images) {
            return response.status(400).json({
                status: false,
                message: "No image provided",
                data: null,
            });
        }

        const imagesArr = await uploadMultipleImage(request.files.images, []);
        if (!imagesArr) {
            return response.status(400).json({
                status: false,
                message: "Error While Adding Product Image",
                data: null,
            });
        }
        const addProductQuantity = await Product.findOneAndUpdate(
            {
                _id: id,
            },
            {
                $push: {
                    singleImage: {
                        color: color,
                        images: imagesArr[0],
                    },
                    images: {
                        color: color,
                        images: imagesArr,
                    },
                },
            },
            {
                new: true,
            },
        );

        response.json({
            status: true,
            message: "Product Image Added Successfully",
            data: addProductQuantity,
        });

    } catch (e) {
        console.log("e", e);
        return response.status(500).json({
            status: false,
            message: "Something went wrong. Please try again",
            data: null,
        });
    }
};
```

Here is GCP code where I'm tring to upload Images using this below code

```
const uploadFileToGCS = async (fileName, fileData) => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve) => {
        try {
            const file = bucket.file(fileName);
            const options = {
                resumable: true,
                // predefinedAcl: "publicRead",
            };
            await file
                .save(fileData.data, options)
                .then(() => {
                    resolve(true);
                })
                .catch((e) => {
                    resolve(false);
                });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("e",error)
            resolve(false);
        }
    });
};

const uploadMultipleImage = async (images, oldArr) => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve) => {
      let fileArr = oldArr;
      try {
        await Promise.all(
          images.map(async (element) => {
            const fileName = `product/${new Date().getTime()}${path.extname(element.name)}`;
            const Uploaded = await uploadFileToGCS(fileName, element);
            console.log("%c Line:16  Uploaded", "color:#33a5ff", Uploaded);
            if (Uploaded === false) {
              resolve(false);
            }
            fileArr.push(fileName);
          })
        );
        resolve(fileArr);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        resolve(false);
      }
    });
  };
```

I'm trying to upload Image to GCP and then store that returned string in DB, but I'm getting this errror.

`{   "success": false,   "message": "404 Not Found" }`
`Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`

Comment: `req.files` doesnt have properties `data`. i saw that you were trying to access property of `Buffer` data. You need to stream the files first and convert them to use type Buffer. you may want to use [Duplex](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#duplex-and-transform-streams) to handle it.

Comment: Still I'm facing same problem. is there any other way to resolve this

Comment: did you use file handler like [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) when requesting files?